# Azure App Registration: Quickstart not working in Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

**What I want:** Connecting a Python Web APP by using Flask with our Azrue AD. We are using Office 365 and Azure.

**What I have tried:** I have tried several times and tutorials from official MS side. But the Quickstart code which MS propose is not working for me. This is the tutorial I have used.
[LINK1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp);[IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP1EC.png);[IMG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkAwU.png)

**What happens:** Each time I can sign in. I get the Webpage with the Sign-in Button. After clicking I get the typical Login Wizzard from Office 365. Everything works. But after finishing that I come back to the Home-site (Log-in-Site). And I get no logfiles from FLASK????? Normaly everything have should work. I found out that is depends on the session.get params in python. But I have no idea how I can solve it.

Hopefully you can help me :)

app.py:

```
import uuid
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_session import Session  # https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session
import msal
import app_config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(app_config)
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not session.get("user"):
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template('index.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    session["state"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    # Technically we could use empty list [] as scopes to do just sign in,
    # here we choose to also collect end user consent upfront
    auth_url = _build_auth_url(scopes=app_config.SCOPE, state=session["state"])
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=auth_url, version=msal.__version__)

@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    if request.args.get('state') != session.get("state"):
        return redirect(url_for("index"))  # No-OP. Goes back to Index page
    if "error" in request.args:  # Authentication/Authorization failure
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=request.args)
    if request.args.get('code'):
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            request.args['code'],
            scopes=app_config.SCOPE,  # Misspelled scope would cause an HTTP 400 error here
            redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()  # Wipe out user and its token cache from session
    return redirect(  # Also logout from your tenant's web session
        app_config.AUTHORITY + "/oauth2/v2.0/logout" +
        "?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + url_for("index", _external=True))

@app.route("/graphcall")
def graphcall():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        app_config.ENDPOINT,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']},
        ).json()
    return render_template('display.html', result=graph_data)


def _load_cache():
    cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()
    if session.get("token_cache"):
        cache.deserialize(session["token_cache"])
    return cache

def _save_cache(cache):
    if cache.has_state_changed:
        session["token_cache"] = cache.serialize()

def _build_msal_app(cache=None, authority=None):
    return msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        app_config.CLIENT_ID, authority=authority or app_config.AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=app_config.CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

def _build_auth_url(authority=None, scopes=None, state=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).get_authorization_request_url(
        scopes or [],
        state=state or str(uuid.uuid4()),
        redirect_uri=url_for("authorized", _external=True))

def _get_token_from_cache(scope=None):
    cache = _load_cache()  # This web app maintains one cache per session
    cca = _build_msal_app(cache=cache)
    accounts = cca.get_accounts()
    if accounts:  # So all account(s) belong to the current signed-in user
        result = cca.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=accounts[0])
        _save_cache(cache)
        return result

app.jinja_env.globals.update(_build_auth_url=_build_auth_url)  # Used in template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

app_config.py:

```
import os

CLIENT_SECRET = "g3nK2F1DX4~_-0Mz-g.XXXXXXXXXXXX" # Our Quickstart uses this placeholder
# In your production app, we recommend you to use other ways to store your secret,
# such as KeyVault, or environment variable as described in Flask's documentation here
# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables
# CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
# if not CLIENT_SECRET:
#     raise ValueError("Need to define CLIENT_SECRET environment variable")

AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"  # For multi-tenant app
# AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Name_Here"

CLIENT_ID = "ff68d6d9-d7a7-4433-a094-XXXXXXXXX"

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # It will be used to form an absolute URL
    # And that absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD

# You can find more Microsoft Graph API endpoints from Graph Explorer
# https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'  # This resource requires no admin consent

# You can find the proper permission names from this document
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference
SCOPE = ["User.ReadBasic.All"]

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # So token cache will be stored in server-side session
```

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable, but perhaps add relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the two important python files I use in my repo. My repo depends, as I wrote above, of the MS Quickstart Repo

Comment: I know it is a StackOverflow recommendation to paste (minimum amount of) source code to demonstrate an issue, but in this particular case, it is unclear to know from your statement of "two files I use in my repo ... [which] depends of the MS Quickstart Repo" - that whether you have made any modification to its original code or not. If their repo won't work out of the box, you will have a legit case for you to create an issue in their github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had also been struggling with this, and it turns out my issue came down to not installing the packages listed in the requirements.txt file correctly.

I had previously played around with flask_sessions and some of the authentication libraries, so had some elements already installed on the environment I was using.  Rather than installing from the requirements.txt provided in the repo, I installed the missing packages manually and encountered the same issue as you describe.

After searching thought the github issues I came across the thread below which indicates there is an issue with the flask-sessions package following a change to one of the dependencies

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/issues/16#issuecomment-618168231

After installing the requirements as per the repo (which installs a forked version of flask-session) the sample worked as expected.

Hope this helps.